# What is the appropriate name for the Present Perfect tense in Spanish?

Tags: verbos

I am unsure how to refer to the Present Perfect tense in Spanish as I teach it.

Is it

- El Presente Perfecto,
- El Preterito Perfecto,
- El Perfecto de Indicativo

or something else?

Comment: Just use the names you find in [conjugation tables](http://www.edu.xunta.es/centros/iesastelleiras/?q=system/files/CONJUGACI%C3%93N+DE+VERBOS+REGULARES.pdf). I think **"pretérito perfecto compuesto (de indicativo/subjuntivo)"** is the term you're looking for. Some people say "**del** indicativo", some say "**de** indicativo", but it doesn't really make any difference. Or you can just omit the mood if it's clear from the context (as generally is the case). Just don't use English terms translated literally—that's more confusing than helpful. Also, in Spanish verb tenses aren't capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of different naming systems for the various tenses (and even the moods to which they pertain!), and different authors have consistently used one or another, and there are valid reasons for using each.

Looking at the temporal and aspectual parts exclusively any of the following, we get the following names:

- **pretérito perfecto compuesto**
  because it takes place in the past (pretérito), is a complete action (perfecto), and uses two words (compuesto)
- **presente perfecto**
  because it is conjugated in the present (presente), but represents a completed action (perfecto)
- **antepresente**
  because it represents an action that occurs before (ante) an action grounded in the present (presente)

All three of these can be represented either in the indicativo (adding *de<sub>(l <sub>(modo)</sub> )</sub> indicativo* or the subjunctive *de<sub>(l <sub>(modo)</sub> )</sub> subjuntivo*).